# Is it possible to specify the indices for K-fold cross-validation with the tune function in R?

Tags: r, svm

I would like to use the `tune()` function in R to specify the hyperparameters in an SVM model. The particular SVM implementation that I am using is the one that is provided in the `e1071` package.

By default, `tune()` runs a K-fold cross-validation, and chooses the testing and training sets for each fold by itself. I am wondering whether I can override this behavior and specify the indices of the testing and training set for each fold myself.

If not, does anyone know if there is a package or combination of packages which allows me to run a K-fold CV on SVM **and** specify the indices of the training and testing set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [caret package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) allows you to specify the training and testing indexes for each fold/resample, using the `indexes` and `indexesOut` arguments of the `trainControl` argument for `train.`

By default, caret uses [kernlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html) for svms, but you can use the `custom` argument for `trainControl` to specify any predictive modeling function you wish.